# Building React component library: how to bundle css and other assets?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So my understanding is that when you are distributing a React component for others to use, you should ship the compiled version of it, rather than the source and expecting the end-user to deal with integrating it into their own build process.

That sounds reasonable, but I am not sure the best strategy for bundling css and other assets like images.

One way would be to inline, but inlining seems discouraged for anything of moderate size.

Another way could be to import the css and images into the file that is importing the component from the library. Then the build process of the end-user's app would handle the rest. Like:

```js
import CoolComponent from 'CoolReactLibrary';
import 'CoolReactLibrary/css/styles.css';
import 'CoolReactLibrary/images/logo.png';

...
```

That seems cumbersome and even more so if I have a component library of a bunch of smaller components like this:

```js
import PrimaryButton from 'CoolReactLibrary/buttons';
import 'CoolReactLibrary/buttons/primary-button/styles.css';

import Card from 'CoolReactLibrary/layout';
import 'CoolReactLibrary/layout/card/styles.css';

import VerticalMenu from 'CoolReactLibrary/menus';
import 'CoolReactLibrary/menus/vertical-navigation/styles.css';
```

My preference would be to just have the end-user do this:

```js
import PrimaryButton from 'CoolReactLibrary/buttons';
import Card from 'CoolReactLibrary/layout';
import VerticalMenu from 'CoolReactLibrary/menus';
```

And everything from there just work.

Anyone find a clean solution for this?

Comment: Have you looked into [`npm publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish)?

Comment: @Adam I am assuming it is published and installed as a NPM package. I could just publish the uncompiled jsx code and the end-user can worry about incorporating into their build process. However, my understanding is that that is not best practice. Instead you should compile it to js as part of the package. My question is what to do with assets like css and images?

Comment: *have a component library of a bunch of smaller components like this* - you can do `import 'CoolReactLibrary/buttons/primary-button/styles.css'` inside respective button module, so a user wouldn't need to do that manually, can't you?

Comment: @estus Not if it is already compiled to javascript, right? If the end-user was using the jsx source then that would be work, but I am interested in shipping already compile javascript.

Comment: This depends on your setup which isn't shown here, Webpack CSS loader configuration in particular. Generally, `import 'CoolReactLibrary/buttons/primary-button/styles.css'` will load CSS programmatically and thus styles will persist in compiled library JS. You can check it yourself.

Comment: The end user shouldn't have to mess with your CSS, so it should be bundled with everything else. This allows them to use one import statement to import the component and its CSS.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out a way to bundle the css and image assets?